# Create divs using start/pause button

Tags: javascript, button, while-loop

I'm trying to use the button while the value is set to "Start" to proggresively create red circles untill I press the button and it is switched to "Pause", therefore stopping the red circle creation.

The problem is when I press the "start" button the browser crashes.

```
var actionBtn = document.querySelector(".btn");

function changeState(){
  if ( actionBtn.value == "Start" ) {
    actionBtn.value = "Pause";
  }
  else {
    actionBtn.value = "Start";
  }
}

function addElem(){
  while ( actionBtn.value == "Start" ) {
    var elemCreate = document.createElement("div");
    elemCreate.className = "circle";
    document.querySelector(".appWrap").appendChild(elemCreate);
  }
}

actionBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  changeState();
  addElem();
});
```

Comment: you can not use a while like that, the loop will not allow the other events to fire.

Comment: What can I write to stop the loop when the button is set to "stop" ?

Comment: Without some form of timing, the browser is going to create more elements than you can imagine....and always crash. A few thousand per second probably

Comment: use `var func= setInterval(addElem, 1000);` to regularly call the function and remove the  while loop in addElem and replace it with if condition,  if u want to stop it when change state of action button write in the add event listener after the call to addElem function `if(actionBtn.Value != "start") { ClearTimeout(func);}`

Comment: @Nadeem I've got it using setInterval. The problem is, if I press the button one time it generates a circle once every second, if I press it again, it generates circles faster, if I press it again, even faster. What could the issue be ?

Comment: @TudorApostol keep your `var func = setInterval(addElem, 1000);` in if condition, like this `var func; if(actionBtn.value == 'Start' && func){ var func= setInterval(addElem, 1000);}else {ClearTimeout(func); func = null;}` if there is already func created don't create new one and in else after cleartimeout assign null value to func.

Comment: Declare var yourVariable in global scope with some value and then on click button code `if(actionBtn.value == 'Start' && yourVariable){ yourVariable= setInterval(addElem, 1000);}else {ClearTimeout(yourVariable); yourVariable = null;}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setTimeout or setInterval and not a while loop. The while loop is going to lock up the browser and you will not be able to flip the bit that you are using to end the loop. Plus the while loop runs really fast so you will get a lot of elements added in a short time. With timers, you can control the rate.

```
function addElem(){
    var elemCreate = document.createElement("div");
    elemCreate.className = "circle";
    document.querySelector(".appWrap").appendChild(elemCreate);
}

var timer;
function changeState(){
  if ( actionBtn.value == "Start" ) {
    actionBtn.value = "Pause";
    timer = window.setInterval(addElem, 500);
  }
  else {
    actionBtn.value = "Start";
    window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know it works with setInterval, just wanted to try and accomplish the same result using a while loop